# Piping readable stream using superagent

Tags: node.js, multer, superagent

I'm trying to create a [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/StorageEngine.md) middleware to pipe a streamed file from the client, to a 3rd party via [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#piping-data).

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
const multer = require('multer');

// my middleware
function streamstorage(){
    function StreamStorage(){}

    StreamStorage.prototype._handleFile = function(req, file, cb){
        console.log(file.stream)  // <-- is readable stream
        const post = superagent.post('www.some-other-host.com');

        file.stream.pipe(file.stream);

        // need to call cb(null, {some: data}); but how
        // do i get/handle the response from this post request?
    }
    return new StreamStorage()
}

const streamMiddleware = {
    storage: streamstorage()
}

app.post('/someupload', streamMiddleware.single('rawimage'), function(req, res){
    res.send('some token based on the superagent response')
});
```

I think this seems to work, but I'm not sure how to handle the response from superagent `POST` request, since I need to return a token received from the superagent request.

I've tried `post.end(fn...)` but apparently `end` and `pipe` [can't both be used together](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/684#issuecomment-233959045). I feel like I'm misunderstanding how piping works, or if what i'm trying to do is practical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Superagent's `.pipe()` method is for downloading (piping data from a remote host to the local application).

It seems you need piping in the other direction: upload from your application to a remote server. In superagent (as of v2.1) there's no method for that, and it requires a different approach.

You have two options:

The easiest, less efficient one is:

Tell multer to buffer/save the file, and then upload the whole file using `.attach()`.

The harder one is to "pipe" the file "manually":

1. Create a superagent instance with URL, method and HTTP headers you want for uploading,
2. Listen to `data` events on the incoming file stream, and call superagent's `.write()` method with each chunk of data.
3. Listen to the `end` event on the incoming file stream, and call superagent's `.end()` method to read server's response.

Comment: That makes sense. Im currently doing the first suggestion, so I'll try the second solution.